# mysql find records in a table that reference records that don't exist

Tags: mysql

In mysql, if I have a record that references the id of another record.  For example

```
Table 1
id          bigint
tabe2ref    bigint

Table 2
id          bigint
```

Where table2ref simply references Table2.id.
Is there a way to list all records in table 1 that reference a record in table 2 where that record doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a `LEFT JOIN` - everything where the entry in table 2 is not existing will have a `null` for the `table2.id` after joining:

```
SELECT 
    table1.id, table1.table2ref, table2.id 
FROM  
    table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 
ON 
    table1.table2ref = table2.id
WHERE
   ISNULL(table2.id) -- only those records with missing reference.
```

See also: http://giannopoulos.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/BHVicYICMAAdHGv.jpg
(first column, second row)

Answer (score 3):

If you want the data from table2 as well, use a LEFT JOIN as in dognose's answer. If you only want the data from table1, use a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table2ref NOT IN (
    SELECT id FROM table2
)
```

Essentially, this reads "get everything from table 1 and subtract all rows which have a table2ref that isn't in all rows in table2."